# How to pass arguments of optional dependencies as params in objective c framework function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an objective c framework to be used by other fellow developers.

In this framework I would like to use if available classes from other frameworks optionally if they are available.

For example, at the moment I am using AdSupport.framework(if is available - linked by the app developer) with the following approach:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
        NSString adString = [[[NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager") sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
}
```

However now, I want to have arguments of public functions of my framework to include classes of optional dependencies and I am not able to do that.

For example:

I want to have a function:

```
+ (void) sendLocation: (CLLocation *) myLoc;
```

but CoreLocation.framework will be optionally linked and maybe not available to an app. How can I follow a similar approach with AdSupport.framework above?

I assumed I could do something like this:

```
+ (void) sendLocation: (NSClassFromString(@"CLLocation") *) myLoc;
```

or

```
+ (void) sendLocation: (id) myLoc;
```

or

```
+ (void) sendLocation: (Class) myLoc;
```

and then extract somehow coordinates but was not able to achieve that. Last option (Class) seems to compile but I cannot find a way to extract params..

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Short example with MapKit (will not be linked to your app unless you request it)

Header:

```
@class MKMapView;
@interface MyTestInterface : NSObject
+ (void)printMapViewDescription:(MKMapView *)mapView;
@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "MyTestInterface.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation

+ (void)printMapViewDescription:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    if ((NSClassFromString(@"MKMapView")) {
       NSLog(@"%@", mapView);
    } else {
       NSLog(@"MapKit not available");
    }
}

@end
```

So you link to the headers internal. This will only work if you provide binaries, or use apple-frameworks only. If you provide the sourcecode and you want to interact with third-party frameworks you have to work with performSelector, NSInvocation or the objc-runtime on anonymous objects (id).

EDIT:

Example with NSInvocation

Header:

```
@class MKMapView;
@interface MyTestInterface : NSObject
+ (void)printMapViewFrame:(MKMapView *)mapView;
@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "MyTestInterface.h"

@implementation

+ (void) printMapViewFrame:(id)mapView {
    if ([mapView respondsToSelector:@selector(frame)]) {
        NSMethodSignature *sig = [mapView methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(frame)];
        if (sig) {
            NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
            [invocation setTarget: mapView];
            [invocation setSelector:@selector(frame)];
            [invocation invoke];
            CGRect rect;
            [invocation getReturnValue:&rect];
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
        }
    }
}

@end
```